# Baixar dados do banco no formato csv

Tags: java, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando baixar os dados do banco em formato csv mas fica indicando que a syntax do SQL está errada.

```
public void exportarBaseRespostaPI() {
    String banco = "b2wentregascorreios";
    String tabela = "baserespmanifest";
    String caminho = "C:\\Users\\wesley.costa\\Desktop\\wesley.costa\\backup-correios\\base_resposta_pi\\base_resposta_pi.csv";
    new File(caminho).delete();
    try (Connection conn = connBD.Conectar(banco); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        try {
            stmt.execute("SELECT `codCorreio`, `codPI`, `respostaMsg`, `dataResp`\r\n" + " FROM " + tabela
                    + "INTO OUTFILE '" + caminho + "' \n"
                    + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' \n" + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Essa é a exception:

> (conn=127002095) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'OUTFILE
>   'C:\Users\wesley.costa\Desktop\wesley.costa\backup-correios\base_respost'
>   at line 2 SELECT codCorreio, codPI, respostaMsg, dataResp FROM
>   baserespmanifest INTO OUTFILE
>   'C:\Users\wesley.costa\Desktop\wesley.costa\backup-correios\base_resposta_pi\base_resposta_pi.csv'
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ';

Comment: coloca na pergunta a string exatamente como vai ser executada

Comment: Adicione a exception que está sendo apresentada.

Comment: Vai sair assim: SELECT `codCorreio`, `codPI`, `respostaMsg`, `dataResp`
 FROM baserespmanifest INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\wesley.costa\Desktop\wesley.costa\backup-correios\base_resposta_pi\base_resposta_pi.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '
';

Comment: Essa é a exception: (conn=127002095) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTFILE 'C:\Users\wesley.costa\Desktop\wesley.costa\backup-correios\base_respost' at line 2

Comment: @WesleyFerreiraCosta Você pode [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar informações. Fica bem melhor e mais legível do que nos comentários.

Comment: Claro pode deixar

Comment: Melhor coisa é quebrar em outros métodos, fazer a consulta, trazer o que precisa para um lista, e depois gerar um método que monta o CSV